# How do I convert an interface into a MonoBehavior in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, monobehaviour

In my method iTest.doStuff(), I try to convert interface testInterf _ti into a MonoBehavior.  This gives me "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MonoBehavior' could not be found", but in the same file, my class iTest has no trouble inheriting from MonoBehavior.

```
//testInterface.cs

using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface testInterf{//this is my interface
    string Name {get;}
    Sprite mySprite {get;}
    void func();
}

public class testInterfEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public testInterf i;

    public testInterfEventArgs(testInterf _i){
        i=_i;
    }
}

//iTest.cs

using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class iTest : MonoBehaviour{
    public void doStuff(testInterf _ti){//this is the implementation
        Collider collider = (_ti as MonoBehavior).GetComponent<Collider>();//ERROR
    }
}
```

Comment: It's MonoBehavio**u**r. Not MonoBehavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(_ti as MonoBehaviour)`

MonoBehavi**ou**r is spelled the British English way - with ou.

But do not get the impression that Unity does consistently use British English spelling. Other classes like `Color` use the American English spelling.